# `help.search()` returns error in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

In **RStudio**,

```
help.search('slider')
```

Returns this error:

`Error in vignette_type(Outfile) : Vignette product ‘NA’ does not have a known filename extension (‘NA’)`

However:

- Other searches (such as `help.search('ARMA')`) appear to be working correctly in **RStudio**.
- Running `help.search('slider')`in the **R for Mac OS X GUI** works as expected.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

---

#### Setup:

MBP OS X Version 10.9.4
RStudio Version 0.98.978
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10) -- "Sock it to Me"

Comment: Works fine for me. R: 3.1.0, RStudio Version 0.98.953, Mac OSX Version 10.9.4

Comment: @ScottRitchie: The `help.search('slider')` command works? Or just the function in general? Also, do you have the **manipulate** package installed?

Comment: Ok, great -- either it's specifically related to **RStudio**'s 0.98.978 update or it's only on *my* comp...

Comment: Specifically `help.search('slider')` works for me.

Comment: same error on OSX 10.10.5 with R 3.2.3 and RStudio Version 0.99.878: `??html` rises and error, so does `??slider`.